# Reset all entries and checkboxes regardless of current state, which were created in a foe loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a few `checkboxes` that enable entry widgets, all works fine.
I need to add a global reset button to clear my entry boxes (I'm using `entry.delete(0, END))`,
which works fine, and I clear various `checkboxes` with `ckbx.deselect()`. So far so good.

However, I have one block of code that uses a loop to create multiple entry & `checkbutton` rows (courtesy of help from here).  BUT, I'm struggling to get my reset button to clear all these entries & deselect the checkbuttons.  Below is the code I have for this section, which I need my global reset to return all to blank entries & deselect all `checkbuttons`.

Any help much appreciated.

Here is a cut down version of (hopefully) operational GUI.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tktooltip import ToolTip
from tkinter import messagebox

debug_on = TRUE

#################################################################################
##   A class to limit the entry size, constrain length to, eg, 2 or 3 digits   ##
#################################################################################
class EntryLen(Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, max_len=1, max_val=1, **kwargs):
        self.var = StringVar()
        self.max_len = max_len
        self.max_val = max_val
        Entry.__init__(self, master, textvariable=self.var, **kwargs)
        self.old_value = ''
        self.var.trace('w', self.check)

    def check(self, *args):
        current_value = self.var.get()
        if (current_value.isdigit() and 
            len(current_value) <= self.max_len and 
            int(current_value) <= self.max_val):
            self.old_value = current_value
        elif current_value == "":
            self.old_value = current_value
        else:
            self.var.set(self.old_value)
#################################################################################
root = Tk()
root.title("Zwift Workout Builder. (Written for my Cycling Club)")
## Some default values for fonts:
frm_font    = tkFont.Font(size=14)
add_font    = tkFont.Font(size=16)
main_font   = tkFont.Font(size=18)
mbk_font    = tkFont.Font(size=8)
DisabledColour="dark grey"

zdat = [] # The global LIST that all workout blocks  get added to.

def Quit_gui():
    response=messagebox.askyesno("Exit App?", "Are you sure you want to quit?\n(You could use the top/right X to kill app!)")
    if response == 1:
        root.destroy()
    else:
        response=messagebox.showinfo("Not Quitting!", "Stay around and see what's possible :-)")
        return

#################################################################################
##                      Create user & workout frames etc                       ##
#################################################################################

frm_user    = Frame(root, relief=RIDGE, bd=4)
frm_main    = Frame(root, relief=RAISED, bd=6)
# Create frames for the workout blocks
frm_warm = Frame(root, relief=RAISED, bd=2)
frm_blck = Frame(root, relief=RAISED, bd=2)
frm_cool = Frame(root, relief=RAISED, bd=2)
frm_free = Frame(root, relief=RAISED, bd=2)
frm_ints = Frame(root, relief=RAISED, bd=2)
frm_mult = Frame(root, relief=RAISED, bd=2)

frm_text     = Frame(root, relief=RAISED, bd=2)
frm_del      = Frame(root, relief=RAISED, bd=2)
################################################################################
##                          User info frame                                   ##
################################################################################

#   Create labels for the user information
lbl_user     = Label(frm_user, text = "User Information", font="arial", relief=RAISED, bd=2)
lbl_name     = Label(frm_user, text = "Name or Inititials", relief=RAISED, bd=2)
lbl_desc     = Label(frm_user, text = "Description", relief=RAISED, bd=2)
lbl_tag1    = Label(frm_user, text = "TAG name1", relief=RAISED, bd=2)
lbl_ftp      = Label(frm_user, text = "Your FTP (W)", relief=RAISED, bd=2)
lbl_filename = Label(frm_user, text = "Filename", relief=RAISED, bd=2)

#   Create entry widgets for the user information
ent_name     = Entry(frm_user, width = 20)
ent_desc     = Entry(frm_user, width = 20)
ent_tag1     = Entry(frm_user, width = 20)
ent_ftp      = EntryLen(frm_user, max_len=3, max_val=999, width=3)
ent_filename = Entry(frm_user, width = 20)

#   Place the user frame in the main root:
frm_user.grid(row=0, column = 0, columnspan = 9)

lbl_user.grid(row=0, column = 0, columnspan=9, sticky="ew", padx=2, pady=2)
lbl_name.grid(row=1, column = 0, sticky="ew", padx=2, pady=2)   
lbl_desc.grid(row=1, column = 1, sticky="ew", padx=2, pady=2)  
lbl_tag1.grid(row=1,  column = 2, sticky="ew", padx=2, pady=2)     
lbl_ftp.grid(row=1, column = 3, sticky="ew", padx=2, pady=2)    
lbl_filename.grid(row=1, column = 6, sticky="ew", padx=2, pady=2)

#   Place the user info entry widgets in the frame;
ent_name.grid(    row=2, column = 0, padx=2, pady=2)   
ent_desc.grid(    row=2, column = 1, padx=2, pady=2)  
ent_tag1.grid(     row=2, column = 2, padx=2, pady=2)     
ent_ftp.grid(    row=2, column = 3, padx=2, pady=2)    
ent_filename.grid(row=2, column = 6, padx=2, pady=2)

def Build_workout(): # Place holder for MRE
    return
def Show_info():
    return
def Reset_all():
    return
def Open_pdf():
    return
#################################################################################
##                  Warmup frame - all widgets have a '_W' suffix              ##
#################################################################################
def Add_Warmup():
    global zdat
    local_data = []
    min=ent_mins_W.get()
    sec=ent_secs_W.get()
    pwr1=ent_pwr1_W.get() # The start power
    pwr2=ent_pwr2_W.get() # The end power
    cad=ent_cadn_W.get()
    if ((min == "") and (sec == "")) or (pwr1 == "") or (pwr2 == ""):
        messagebox.showwarning("WARNING", "DATA MISSING! \n\
                                You must have data for either Mins or Secs!\n\
                                (Mins OR Secs can be blank, but not both.\n\
                                You must have data for start & end power.")
        return
    else: # Time not both "" so set W_Time
        if (min == ""):
            W_time = int(sec)
        elif (sec == ""):
            W_time = int(min)*60
        else:
            W_time = int(min)*60 + int(sec)
        if (cad == ""):
            cad = "X"
        else:
            cad = int(cad)
             
    local_data.append("WARM")
    local_data.append(W_time)
    local_data.append(int(pwr1))
    local_data.append(int(pwr2))
    local_data.append(cad)
    zdat.append(local_data)

    if debug_on:
        debug_window = Toplevel()
        debug_window.title("Debugging as I build,show 'zdat' global.")
        debug = Label(debug_window, text = zdat)
        debug.pack()
##-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# row 0
frm_warm.grid(row=1, column = 0, padx=10, pady=10)
lbl_name_W    = Label(frm_warm, text = "WARMUP", relief=RIDGE, bd=2, fg="RED", font=frm_font)
lbl_name_W.grid(row=0, column = 0, columnspan = 8, sticky="ew", padx=2, pady=2) 
# row 1
lbl_mins_W    = Label(frm_warm, text = "Min")
lbl_coln_W    = Label(frm_warm, text = ":")
lbl_secs_W    = Label(frm_warm, text = "Sec")
lbl_pwr1_W    = Label(frm_warm, text = "Start(pwr)")
lbl_pwr2_W    = Label(frm_warm, text = "End(pwr)")
lbl_cadn_W    = Label(frm_warm, text = "Cad")
         
lbl_mins_W.grid(row=1, column = 1)
lbl_coln_W.grid(row=1, column = 2)
lbl_secs_W.grid(row=1, column = 3)
lbl_pwr1_W.grid(row=1, column = 5)
lbl_pwr2_W.grid(row=1, column = 6)
lbl_cadn_W.grid(row=1, column = 7)
         
# row 2
lbl_time_W    = Label(frm_warm, text = "Time")
ent_mins_W    = EntryLen(frm_warm, max_len=2, max_val=99, width=2)
ent_secs_W    = EntryLen(frm_warm, max_len=2, max_val=60, width=2)
lbl_pwr3_W    = Label(frm_warm, text = "Power")
ent_pwr1_W    = EntryLen(frm_warm, max_len=3, max_val=999, width=3)
ent_pwr2_W    = EntryLen(frm_warm, max_len=3, max_val=999, width=3)
ent_cadn_W    = EntryLen(frm_warm, max_len=3, max_val=150, width=3)

lbl_time_W.grid(row=2, column = 0)
ent_mins_W.grid(row=2, column = 1)
ent_secs_W.grid(row=2, column = 3)
lbl_pwr3_W.grid(row=2, column = 4)
ent_pwr1_W.grid(row=2, column = 5)
ent_pwr2_W.grid(row=2, column = 6)
ent_cadn_W.grid(row=2, column = 7)

but_add_W     = Button(frm_warm, text="ADD Warmup", relief=RIDGE, bd=2, bg="lightblue", fg="blue", font=add_font, command = Add_Warmup)
but_add_W.grid(row=4, column = 0, columnspan = 8, sticky="ew", padx=2, pady=2) 

##################################################################################
##              Multi_Blocks frame -                                            ##
##################################################################################
def ADD_mb_data():
    global zdat
    local_data = []
    local_data.append("MBLK")   # Unique ID for this block
    for i in range(mb_size):
        #if mb_vars[i] == 0:
        if mb_vars[i] == 1:
            # Get the time, power & cadence for that row into a list
            # Only cadence can be blank, add an 'X' for blank cadence
            # to keep the list a multiple of 3 (but with extra "MB" at start).
            mins = mb_mins[i].get()
            secs = mb_secs[i].get()
            pwr  = mb_pwr[i].get()
            cad  = mb_cad[i].get()
            rpts = e_repeats.get()
            if ((mins == "") and (secs == "")) or (pwr == "") or (rpts == ""): 
                messagebox.showwarning("WARNING", "DATA MISSING! \nYou must have data for Power \nand for either Mins or Secs!\n(Mins or Sec can be blank, but not both.\n Number or repeats cannot be blank (1 to 50 allowed).\nCad is optional).")
                return  # Need to put WARNING/ERROR message here!
            else:
                if secs == "":
                    secs = 0
                elif mins == "":
                    mins = 0
                    
                time = int(mins)*60 + int(secs)
                local_data.append(time)
                local_data.append(int(pwr))
                if cad == "":
                    local_data.append("X")
                else:
                    local_data.append(int(cad))
                    
    local_data.append(int(rpts))
    zdat.append(local_data) #Get the local into the gloabal zdat

    if debug_on:
        debug_window = Toplevel()
        debug_window.title("Debugging as I build, show 'zdat' global.")
        debug = Label(debug_window, text = zdat)
        debug.pack()
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mb_mins = []
mb_secs = []
mb_pwr  = []
mb_cad  = []
mb_vars = []

lbl_name_MB    = Label(frm_mult, text = "MULTI-BLOCK", relief=RAISED, bd=2, width = 20, fg = "blue", font=frm_font)
lbl_name_MB.grid(row=0, column = 0, columnspan = 8, sticky="ew", padx=2, pady=2) 

mb_size = 10     # The number of rows required (probably about 15 TBD)?
frm_mult.grid(row=1, column = 4, rowspan = 5, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10, sticky = "n")

def set_state(i):
    #if mb_vars[i]==0:
    if mb_vars[i]==1:
        new_state = "disabled"
        #mb_vars[i]=1
        mb_vars[i]=0
    else:
        new_state = "normal"
        #mb_vars[i]=0
        mb_vars[i]=1
    mb_mins[i].configure(state=new_state)
    mb_secs[i].configure(state=new_state)
    mb_pwr[i].configure(state=new_state)
    mb_cad[i].configure(state=new_state)
    
mins    = Label(frm_mult, width=3, text="Mins").grid(row=1, column=0)    
colon   = Label(frm_mult, width=1, text=":").grid(row=1, column=1)
secs    = Label(frm_mult, width=3, text="Secs").grid(row=1, column=2)    
space1  = Label(frm_mult, width=1, text=" ").grid(row=1, column=3)
power   = Label(frm_mult, width=3, text="Pwr").grid(row=1, column=4)
space2  = Label(frm_mult, width=1, text=" ").grid(row=1, column=5) 
cadence = Label(frm_mult, width=3, text="Cad").grid(row=1, column=6)
Enable  = Label(frm_mult, width=5, text="Enable").grid(row=1, column=7)

for i in range(mb_size):
    mins = EntryLen(frm_mult, max_len=2, max_val=99, width=2, state = "disabled", disabledbackground=DisabledColour)
    mins.grid(row=i+2, column=0)
    secs = EntryLen(frm_mult, max_len=2, max_val=60, width=2, state = "disabled", disabledbackground=DisabledColour)
    secs.grid(row=i+2, column=2)
    powr = EntryLen(frm_mult, max_len=3, max_val=999, width=3, state = "disabled", disabledbackground=DisabledColour)
    powr.grid(row=i+2, column=4)
    cdnc = EntryLen(frm_mult, max_len=3, max_val=150, width=3, state = "disabled", disabledbackground=DisabledColour)
    cdnc.grid(row=i+2, column=6)
    mb_mins.append(mins)   # Add the minutes to the list
    mb_secs.append(secs)   # Add the seconds to the list
    mb_pwr.append(powr)    # Add the power(W) to the list
    mb_cad.append(cdnc)    # Add the cadence to the list

for key in range(mb_size):
    var = IntVar(value=0)
    mb_vars.append(var)
    cb = Checkbutton(frm_mult,command=lambda i=key: set_state(i))
    cb.grid(row=key+2,column=7)
    
l_uscrmb    = Label(frm_mult, text="---------------XXXXXX----------------").grid(row=mb_size+3, column=0, columnspan= 9)
l_repeats   = Label(frm_mult, text="No. of Blk(s) repeats?").grid(row=mb_size+4, column=1, columnspan= 4)
e_repeats   = EntryLen(frm_mult, max_len=2, max_val=50, width=2)
e_repeats.grid(row=mb_size+4, column=6)    
but_add_MB     = Button(frm_mult, text="ADD Multi-Blocks", relief=RAISED, bd=2, bg="lightblue", fg="blue", font=add_font, command = ADD_mb_data)
but_add_MB.grid(row=mb_size+5, column = 0, columnspan = 10, sticky="ew", padx=2, pady=2)
##################################################################################
##                              MAIN  frame                                     ##
##################################################################################
frm_main.grid(row=7, column = 0, columnspan=7, padx=10, pady=10, sticky = "s")
but_build       = Button(frm_main, text="BUILD",     relief=RAISED, width=10, bd=4, bg="blue", fg="yellow",font=main_font, command = Build_workout, padx=10, pady=5)
but_info        = Button(frm_main, text="INFO",      relief=RAISED, width=10, bd=4, bg="lightgreen", fg="black",font=main_font, command = Show_info, padx=10, pady=5)
but_reset       = Button(frm_main, text="RESET",     relief=RAISED, width=10, bd=4, bg="white", fg="red",font=main_font, command = Reset_all, padx=10, pady=5)
but_quit        = Button(frm_main, text="QUIT",      relief=RAISED, width=10, bd=4, bg="red", fg="white",font=main_font, command = Quit_gui, padx=10, pady=5)
but_docs        = Button(frm_main, text="Docs",      relief=RAISED, width=10, bd=4, bg="red", fg="white",font=main_font, command = Open_pdf, padx=10, pady=5)
but_build.grid(row=0, column=0)
but_info.grid(row=0, column=1)
but_reset.grid(row=0, column=4)
but_quit.grid(row=0, column=5)
but_docs.grid(row=0, column=6)
################################################################################
root.mainloop()
################################################################################
```

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre]. What is `EntryLen`?

Comment: A subclass of Entry that only allows digits, constrains the length and the max value allowed.

Comment: Hopefully I've not overdone the MRE, but thought it needed that much to show what I have (there are 4 or 5 more input boxes I've deleted for this MRE.  I've workout out how to reset all in the WARMUP block, but not for the MULTI_BLOCK, where the widgets are created in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `mb_vars` is a list of instances of `IntVar()`, but you overwrite it with *integers* inside `set_state()`:

```py
def set_state(i):
    #if mb_vars[i]==0:
    if mb_vars[i]==1:
        new_state = "disabled"
        #mb_vars[i]=1
        mb_vars[i]=0  ### overwrite mb_vars[i] to integer
    else:
        new_state = "normal"
        #mb_vars[i]=0
        mb_vars[i]=1  ### overwrite mb_vars[i] to integer
    mb_mins[i].configure(state=new_state)
    mb_secs[i].configure(state=new_state)
    mb_pwr[i].configure(state=new_state)
    mb_cad[i].configure(state=new_state)
```

You should add `variable=var` to associate the `IntVar()` to the checkbutton when creating it and then use `mb_vars[i].get()` instead to get the checked state of the checkbutton inside `set_state()`:

```py
def set_state(i):
    state = NORMAL if mb_vars[i].get() else DISABLED
    mb_mins[i].configure(state=state)
    mb_secs[i].configure(state=state)
    mb_pwr[i].configure(state=state)
    mb_cad[i].configure(state=state)

...

# combined two for loops into one
for i in range(mb_size):
    mins = EntryLen(frm_mult, max_len=2, max_val=99, width=2, state=DISABLED, disabledbackground=DisabledColour)
    mins.grid(row=i+2, column=0)
    secs = EntryLen(frm_mult, max_len=2, max_val=60, width=2, state=DISABLED, disabledbackground=DisabledColour)
    secs.grid(row=i+2, column=2)
    powr = EntryLen(frm_mult, max_len=3, max_val=999, width=3, state=DISABLED, disabledbackground=DisabledColour)
    powr.grid(row=i+2, column=4)
    cdnc = EntryLen(frm_mult, max_len=3, max_val=150, width=3, state=DISABLED, disabledbackground=DisabledColour)
    cdnc.grid(row=i+2, column=6)
    mb_mins.append(mins)   # Add the minutes to the list
    mb_secs.append(secs)   # Add the seconds to the list
    mb_pwr.append(powr)    # Add the power(W) to the list
    mb_cad.append(cdnc)    # Add the cadence to the list

    var = IntVar(value=0)
    mb_vars.append(var)
    # added variable=var
    cb = Checkbutton(frm_mult, variable=var, command=lambda i=i: set_state(i))
    cb.grid(row=i+2, column=7)
```

And the `Reset_all()` function as below:

```py
def Reset_all():
    for i in range(mb_size):
        # clear entry boxes
        for lst in (mb_mins, mb_secs, mb_pwr, mb_cad):
            lst[i].configure(state=NORMAL)
            lst[i].delete(0, END)
            lst[i].configure(state=DISABLED)
        # clear checkbutton
        mb_vars[i].set(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for all that.  I had wondered about the way I was changing state.  I'll try & update my code in a few days or so to employ all your advice & code, thank you.

Comment: Thank you acw1668, my code now looks a lot neater and it all works as I intended (so far); had to tweak a few other minor bits to match the "mb_vars[i].get()" rather than the way I'd done it.  Just the reset bit to try out now.  